# How can i change the hit distance of RaycastHit?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using this script to send a raycast from the center of the camera to objects.
It's working fine but only if i'm getting close enough to objects. But for example if it's npc person i want to be able to detect him as "Interactable" from a more distance. How can i change/set the hit distance ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRaycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Interactable")
            {
                print("I'm looking at " + hit.transform.name);
            }
            else
                print("I'm looking at nothing!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html you'll find that the function is overloaded. The very next parameter you can add is distance:

```
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you are aware of the Vector3 you are passing as a parameter you are giving to **Camera.ViewportToRay()**, that is a normalized space (I think that it is a Moebius Space). You are giving to z a 0 parameter, so the ray would reach the start of the viewport, you may play with values between 0.1-1.0 for z, to deal with distance.

Another solution, would be to instance a Ray using the Camera's position as reference, but without using ViewportToRay().

Something like this (you may use transform.forward, instead of TransformDirection):

```
    public float distance;  /// Distance of your Ray.
    public Camera camera;   /// The camera (duh).

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.TransformDirection(0f, 0f, distance));
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        if (hit.transform.tag == "Interactable")
        {
            print("I'm looking at " + hit.transform.name);
        }
        else print("I'm looking at nothing!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This is what worked for me:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);
```